# CPaintDC(this) in CStatic derived class paints outside of control

Tags: mfc, gdi

As the title says.
Even with CPaintDC in the derived class the GDI drawing is not cut off.
Thanks in advance.

```
void CGraph::OnPaint ()
{
   CPaintDC dc(this);
   dc.SetViewportOrg (0, 400);
   dc.SetMapMode(MM_ISOTROPIC);
   dc.SetWindowExt(1000, 800);
   dc.SetViewportExt(1000, -800);

   // MessageBox(L"OnPaint");
   ProcessData ();
   DrawCoordinateSystem (&dc);
   DrawGrid (&dc);
   DrawGraph (&dc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I solved the problem

```
    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    CRect rClient(0,0,1000,800);
    //GetClientRect(rClient);
    CRgn ClipRgn;

    if (ClipRgn.CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClient))
    {
        pDC->SelectClipRgn(&ClipRgn);
    }

    pDC->SelectObject (PenBlack);
    pDC->MoveTo (-leftMargin*zoomWidth, setPointsCorrected);
    pDC->LineTo (1000*zoomWidth, setPointsCorrected);

    pDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

Comment: This example is maybe not 'wrong' in the strict sense that it won't work, but at the least using several win32 concepts wrongly. First, in your original example you were drawing in OnPaint(), here you use GetDC() - in OnPaint(), always get your DC from GetPaintDC() (or use CPaintDC which does it for you). Secondly, setting a clip region to a very large one is the same as SetClipRgn(NULL), as I suggested in my answer below. That way you don't have to create a new GDI object just for setting it to something that means 'the whole control'.

Comment: So you can remove the whole example with CPaintDC dc(this); dc.SelectClipRgn(NULL); dc.MoveTo()/LineTo(); - removing the potential leaking of both the CRgn and the DC. I'm still unsure what exactly was happening in your app at first - what did the cstatic draw on? You say it's in 'the window', but *what* window? I get the feeling you don't really know what's happening and that there are usually *several* windows inside the child windows of an MDI app. If you're not directly setting a clip region, having to clear it is usually a sign that something is off with your window ordering/creation.

Answer (score 2):

So, your CGraph is derived from CStatic, and the drawing code you show draws outside of the CStatic control, onto the dialog it is on? That's impossible, a control can only draw on itself. Are you sure the control isn't bigger than you think it is, and what you think is off-control actually isn't? Use spy++ to select your cstatic, it'll show you the border of the window.

Maybe what you are seeing is improper invalidation. Try dragging another window over your control, see what that does.

Otherwise, the methods to restrict the drawing area are

- You manually track where to draw. Tedious.
- Use SetClipRgn() to set the area to which to restrict drawing.
- Not quite the same, but symptoms sometimes look similar: check the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS and WS_CLIPCHILDREN flags of your control and the dialog it's on.

Comment: Dragging another window over my control does nothing. The drawing remains. Also, the control is in fact smaller than my drawing. By the way, the control isn't on a dialog. It's directly embedded in the view.

Comment: So you're not using a CFormView? Your control is directly in the child window? Have you written your own window creation code? Because within the regular mfc framework, you always need a view control in the window, which is usually a CFormView when there are control inside the window. Onto what does your control draw then? Outside of the main application's window even, are you using an SDI or MDI interface?

Comment: MDI interface, CStatic control inside of the window. It works now by the way.